# Is possible change the image in corona when is inicializate with Lua?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I have an image like this:

```
 myImage = display.display.newImage("/images/resources/res.png")
 myImage.x = 100; myImage.y = 100; myImage.property = "local";
```

and depending of an event, is possible change the src of "`myImage`" image for other without other variable?

```
myImage = display.newImage("/images/resources/res2.png")
```

Comment: For some reason, the update in a local event cause that the variable take the value like null, but, when I change the function like global, the value was accepted

Comment: if your using local function for the object you must put the function at the top of the object because it will not see the function below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't directly change the image itself unless it is an image sheet.

But you can use [image sheet](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/graphics/newImageSheet.html) and [sprite sheet](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/display/newSprite.html). You can change its image whenever you want.

Here's an example

http://www.coronalabs.com/blog/2012/10/02/animated-sprites-and-methods/

Answer (score 0):

```
chosen1pic = "selectCharacter.png"

chosen1 = display.newImage(chosen1pic)
    chosen1.x = display.contentWidth *.75
    chosen1.y = display.contentHeight *.75

choice1 = display.newImage("choice1.png")
    choice1.x = display.contentWidth /8
    choice1.y = display.contentHeight /6

local function removeImagea()
    chosen1: removeSelf()
    end

local function choicea()
    removeImagea()
    chosen2pic = "AVTR1.png"
    chosen2 = display.newImage(chosen2pic)
    chosen2.x = display.contentWidth *.2
    chosen2.y = display.contentHeight *.75
    end

choice1: addEventListener("tap", choicea)
```